# Best approach for uploading image app with possible connection issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, meteor

I have a potential "client" (he's a friend of mine) requesting the following: His company has contractors collecting data of buildings (condition, tenants etc.). They want to optimize this process with a web app / native app on a tablet the contractors have with them to input the data (they are doing it on paper now) and store it in a database. They must also take a picture of the building and attach it to the data set.

I'm capable of creating a web application for the data entries, but I'm wondering what would be the best way to upload the images. You have to consider that at some points, the user will have slow connection (or none at all). A server side solution like rails seems not to be the best way, since users will have to wait until the picture uploads before they can continue to work with the app. On the other hand, I would like to avoid creating a native application with a sync button to upload all new data when pressed. Especially because I generally think a browser based tool is always the more flexible and sustainable solution.

Now I played a bit with meteor, and to my understanding (I’m pretty new to web development), meteor will save everything on the client first and will sync it with the server when accessible. Would that be a good solution for the specs described above? Or would you prefer a container-app like phone-gap?

I don’t want any detailed instructions but just a general opinion on what would be the best way to approach this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think Meteor would be a good solution. If they have it on the phone they can always resend it if something went wrong. Besides that, you probably want to send the data in chunks, so you can start resending from the point where it went wrong and don't have to start all over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meteor currently doesn't have a "standardized" way to upload files(it's on the roadmap). You could look into the atmosphere package [CollectionFS](https://github.com/raix/Meteor-CollectionFS), which from the [demo](http://collectionfs.meteor.com/) I've seen(I use AWS S3 for my file storage needs) it has automatic pause and restart when the server drops out.

Another thing to think about with Meteor is it sounds like you would be tying into an existing database. Meteor currently only supports MongoDB databases. SQL is on the roadmap(unfortunately, IMO) but not integrated yet.

Comment: Thanks Dave for your answer. It seems to me that I'm not on the complete wrong path considering Meteor for this. And: No, I will not connect to an existing database, so the mongo requirement is not an issue here. I've edited the question to be more precise about that.

Comment: Well in that case I'd definitely go with Meteor! It's a lot of fun and really easy to get something built fast, and it's just going to get better as time goes on.